# In Star Trek, do the Greek gods lack nipples?

Tags: star-trek-tos, greek-myth, star-trek

OK, I hope this question doesn't seem prurient, but I happened upon the image and literally couldn't decide what I'm looking at.

In the *TOS* episode "[Who Mourns for Adonais?](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Who_Mourns_for_Adonais%3F_(episode))" we learn that the Greek Gods of Earth were actually powerful aliens, and Apollo is the only one remaining.

Thing is, if you look at this image

[image: Still indicating Apollo]

or this image

[image: Still indicating Apollo and Enterprise crew]

or this image

[image: Still indicating Apollo]

you will see that it's really difficult to distinguish Apollo's nipple.   (I've scaled them to medium size to approximate the broadcast quality of the time -- don't forget how bad SD quality over the airwaves would look.)

## What's going on?

- Is the intent in-universe that the Greek gods lack nipples?   (Why?)
- Did the sensibilities of the time for 60s TV preclude too much male nipple display?
- Is the actor wearing makeup on his chest?   (He is obviously shaved)
- Does this actor just have particularly pale nipples?

Comment: Comments moved [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29215/discussion-on-question-by-thepopmachine-in-star-trek-do-the-greek-gods-lack-nip).

Comment: Why does a God need a nipple?

Comment: I have no doubt that there are whole subgenres of fanfic dealing with ToS male nipples in one way or another.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

First, let's establish that at least some male characters *do* have nipples in *The Original Series* :

[image]

Given what we see above, it's certainly not a general policy on *TOS* to have no nipples. With that out of the way, we can focus on the appearance of the  Greek god Apollo.

Here he is in a larger, better screen capture:

[image]

**There *are* nipples here; they are just especially pale and small.**

Here is another, just for good measure — the nipple, while small, is clearly visible in the lower half of the image:

[image]

So now one can ask: are his nipples naturally pale and small or was something done to them?  The answer is the latter.  Commenting on the controversy over the idea of having the character of Carolyn discover that she is pregnant at the end of the episode, actor Michael Forest (Apollo) said:

> I don’t know. It’s so long ago. I suppose it would have been OK, but you have to remember that in those days, the idea of that sort of thing happening in film, and certainly on television… you couldn’t even talk about it, really. **To give you an idea, they had to put tape on my nipples for that episode. Can you imagine? They put tape on a guy, on a guy’s nipples. I mean, come on. But that’s what they did, and then they put makeup over that.** I thought at the time, “I can’t believe what they’re doing.”

([Source](http://www.startrek.com/article/catching-up-with-star-treks-apollo) — thanks @ThePopMachine)

**So it seems that makeup tape had been placed over his nipple, and then his nipple was remodelled with makeup, possibly to do with taboos at the time, as implied by the actor himself.**

One could ask why the same policy didn't apply to Sulu (or Kirk).  Possibilities:

- Perhaps the Apollo actor's nipples were quite pronounced and edging on "indecent" (by the standards of the show's producers and/or personnel at the time) while Takei's and Shatner's were not.
- Perhaps the actor *believes* that taboos were the reason, but actually had quite off-putting nipples that were not seen to be fitting of a Greek deity. (No offence intended to the actor.)
- Perhaps Takei and Shatner *were* given the same tape/makeup treatment, but theirs came out with better definition in the end.

Regarding the third possibility, the following two images (taken from different episodes) suggest that Shatner had nipple treatment at least some of the time.  **Kirk's nipples are more natural and ample in the first, while in the second they are almost non-existent:**

[image]
[image]

If his nipples were also treated in the first still, then the results of the process were inconsistent, either intentionally or unintentionally depending on the personnel involved and the costuming decisions surrounding those episodes.

Comment: I was expecting a shirtless Kirk picture but I guess that's just too pedestrian for this site.

Comment: May want to look at this http://www.trekbbs.com/showthread.php?t=183164

Comment: And this http://www.startrek.com/article/catching-up-with-star-treks-apollo

Comment: @Praxis:   Maybe it is speculation, but the foundation idea makes sense to me.   Also, I doubt that is a screen capture.   Wouldn't have have to be a photo still to be that detailed?   Therefore not representative of what was broadcast?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I think it is from the remastered version (and I doubt they would have added nipples in the restoration).  Thanks for the startrek.com link; I updated the answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Here is the same still from the original version, also with nipple: http://cdn-www.cracked.com/articleimages/dan/trek/greek.jpg

Comment: @Praxis, so why different rules from Apollo than for Sulu and Kirk?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I don't know. It could be that his nipples were somehow too pronounced (while Kirk's and Sulu's were more even in tone), or it could be that they did the same thing to Kirk and Sulu, but they came out more clearly in their cases.  Anyway, the question(s) posed in the original question have been answered: he does have nipples, but they have been softened, and his implication is that it is due to some odd out-of-universe 1960s taboo.

Comment: Do we need a *size matters* tag?

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I'd say the most likely explanation for why Apollo would be treated differently than Kirk or Sulu percentage of screen-time - Apollo's partially bare chest is part of his costume, his nipple-area would be visible 100% of the time he's on screen.

Comment: @Jason:   Possible, but weren't there episodes where Kirk and Sulu each spend a large fraction of their time shirtless?

Comment: @Praxis:   Actually, I think we can do better.   From [this](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/sgIGK6ypnvE/hqdefault.jpg) TOS image and [this](http://s1.dmcdn.net/AQv79/1280x720-YRO.jpg) image and [this](http://www.splashnewsonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/spl147049_001-wm900.jpg) image (sorry!), I think we can conclude that at least some of the time, Shatner underwent the same treatment in TOS.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: When I get to a computer, I'll add more about Kirk --- thanks.

Comment: Maybe the actor who played Apollo had really big nipples. http://www.celebcosmeticsurgery.com/wp-content/uploads/image-import/_I2j2VVNXosc/TAhTUYZdikI/AAAAAAAAB3Y/QdJwEYO-0Uc/s1600/manboobs.jpg

Comment: +1 *There are nipples here; they are just especially pale and small.*

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Hmmm...on second thought, the third image of Kirk with (presumably natural) nipples is of him coming out of the water...the water temperature may have affected his nipples.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I added some more thoughts on Kirk's nipples, using some other images that are more suitable for comparison.

Comment: As an unpleasant addendum- it has to do with perception of sex. So while Apollo and Kirk are seen as sexual beings, Sulu was not white and therefore wasn't seen as much as a sexual object. Please dont hate on me,  I'm not saying I agree,  only that it's an unpleasant but plausable explanation.

Comment: @Praxis:  Really, no taker on the older photo of Shatner?   Boo!   It was good because it shows his nipples definitely without makeup.  Also, do you think water affects nipple color?

Comment: @Praxis:  Here's more on Apollo.  Apparently [Michael Forest](http://millionmonkeytheater.com/moviepics3/atlasatlas.jpg) had himself a little niche playing mythological Greek figures.  This picture is as Atlas in the 1961 film *Atlas*.   It allows us to conclude he *was* shaven/waxed for TOS.  But also, if anyone can find a better/different capture, it would let us answer the question about the appearance of his nipples without makeup.  (!)

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I've seen countless topless men in the last 24 hours...all because of you. ;-)

Comment: @muistooshort : Your wish is my command. ;-)

Comment: I would have been more impressed by [this one](https://weminoredinfilm.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/star-trek-kirk-and-spock-shirtless-300x245.jpg) or [this one](http://smg.photobucket.com/user/PuppyRanger/media/Tim%20Allen/galaxy-quest-135.jpg.html) (Galaxy Quest is the best Star Trek movie ever made after all). Heh.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is somewhat inadvertent and just a result of body makeup and no one noticing. See Chris Evans basketball scene in "What's Your Number?" In a show like ST, the makeup artists were RARELY dealing with nipples/chests at all... if you are covering a torso with makeup, what do you do.  Not cover the nipple? Cover it and then paint it in with rouge? I suspect in some cases it is lack of time. Some cases it might be too embarrassing to the make up artist. He is wrong that they used tape here. ALSO, it is slightly possible, that there was an idea to make him look like a marble statue of a Greek God, so heavy even makeup over the torso.

Comment: This just seems like a lot of guesswork that is also mainly ruled out by the other answer. Do you have any evidence you could [edit] in for any of this to back it up? I've also removed the irrelevant commentary from the post.