# Was Ezri Dax's hairstyle based on Mirror Jadzia Dax?

Tags: star-trek-ds9, mirror-universe, star-trek

Here are three images of Dax:

Regular Dax:

[image]

Mirror Dax and Ezri Dax:

[image]
[image]

## Was Ezri Dax's hairstyle based on Mirror-Universe Jadzia Dax?

(For example,  perhaps they wanted Ezri to be reminiscent of Jadzia without it looking like they were trying to make her identical.   This will require behind-the-scenes evidence.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While actress Nicole de Boer claims,

> **"I've always worn my hair like this..."**

in the *Deep Space Nine Companion*, I would take this with a grain of salt.  She started playing Ezri in autumn 1998, but in most of her roles in 1997 and prior, she had shoulder-length hair, kept straight and down with no bangs / fringe.  For instance, here she is in the classic Canadian independent sci-fi horror *Cube* (1997):

[image]

Here she is earlier in the same year in the Canadian television series *Ready or Not:*

[image]

The same is true for her earlier roles, as well.  (And since *DS9*, she has gone back to shoulder-length or longer hair with no fringe.)

It seems that she started wearing her hair short in 1998.  Here she is as Yuna in TV series *Mission Genesis* (aka *Deepwater Black*) in early 1998, with shorter hair and some level of sculpting of her bangs / fringe:

[image]

She also had shorter hair in the TV film *My Date with the President's Daughter*, whose filming was completed just prior to her casting in *DS9*.

Since length is a large factor for the ways in which hair can be styled, and since she seems to have been without bangs / fringe prior to 1998, it seems that a more accurate version of her statement is that her style in *DS9* is probably identical to her style at the time she was cast to play Ezri.

Finally, I can find no connection between Ezri's hairstyle and Jadzia's mirror hairstyle.  Ira Steven Behr, the *DS9* showrunner, had a lot of trouble picking someone to play Ezri.  The initial casting call was for someone "spooky", but Behr wasn't happy with any of the auditions.  Eventually, co-supervising producer René Echevarria suggested that the new Dax be less confident and more confused than Jadzia, perhaps because of an unexpected joining with the symbiont. Screenwriter Hans Beimler, upon hearing of this new concept for Ezri, suggested Nicole de Boer, whom he had worked with on some series filmed in Canada.  (This account has been drawn together from several reputable sources — see the references [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezri_Dax).)

Regarding de Boer's audition, Behr remarked:

> **"I can say that when Nikky walked in to audition, she was exactly what I had in mind, the way she looked, the way she acted, just the whole package was exactly what I saw Ezri Dax to be."**

(Source — *DS9* Season 7 DVD Features)

If Behr had mirror Jadzia in mind for Ezri's appearance, he hasn't said so (nor has anyone else involved in the conception of Ezri's character).  It seems from the difficult process of creating Ezri that they knew they were looking for *something*, but couldn't quite put their finger on it, until they met de Boer and saw that she was what they were seeking all along.

Comment: Nice work as always.  Any info on whether they had the same hairstylist?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Thanks!  They did have the same stylist, Norma Lee.  I did try find a statement from Lee, but she hasn't been interviewed.  But Ezri's hair is so close to her hair in *Deepwater Black* and *My Date with the President's Daughter* (both in the months prior to her *DS9* casting) that I suspect they didn't do anything dramatic to her hair.  As Behr said, what he saw in the audition was exactly what he wanted Ezri to be.

Comment: Praxis, I'm having a little trouble with this point of "so close to her hair in...".   There's a lot more to hairstyle than just the length.   (First [male nipples](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102947/in-star-trek-do-the-greek-gods-lack-nipples), now this,  yeesh!)

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Apart from her bangs in *Deepwater Black* (which presumably were shaped to give her character a rebellious note), her style seems identical to that in *DS9*.  It's not just about length.  If there is an unjust focus on length in my answer, I'll rectify that.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Note that I'm including the images to only to counter her claim that she's "always worn her hair like this".  It's easier to say when two styles are different than the same, because of subjectivity on the part of the viewer.  The important thing is that she said they used the style she happened to have when they hired her, and Behr thought her look in the audition was perfect.  There's no evidence they wanted to find or sculpt another Jadzia...

Comment: @ThePopMachine : By subjectivity, I mean that you see a resemblance between Jadzia's mirror universe style and Ezri's style, but they're not that close to me.  The way Jadzia's hair is allowed to hang close to the eye and the looseness of the hair below her ears are big differences for me.  The similarity to me is mostly the length.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it was just a coincidence. *Deep Space Nine Companion* includes a quote from Nicole deBoer about her hair, where she suggests that she brought that hairstyle with her:

> "I've always worn my hair like this, although for *Star Trek* it's glued down so nothing moves," laughs deBoer.
>
> <sup><sub>[*Deep Space Nine Companion* "Afterimage"](https://books.google.ca/books?id=kDe3VS07YSMC&pg=PA605&lpg=PA605&dq=ezri+dax%27s+hair&source=bl&ots=hQmvrHr-G-&sig=aQaq6fbE3c9fNgBPjMbA52Fb5G4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBzgUahUKEwjRrpvj6snIAhUEkw0KHeakDTA#v=onepage&q=%22I%27ve%20always%20worn%20my%20hair%20like%20this&f=false)</sub></sup>