# Name of Story about Jehovah and Satan making stable reality out of chaos

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Recently read a story that now I cannot remember the name, or the writer.  An entertaining short story that explores the relationship between Satan and Jehovah, along with a cast of the Heavenly Host (archangel Michael, even Jesus!). It deals with how Jehovah and Satan are the first entities to self-realize out of a maelstrom of chaos, and the secret grand plan Jehovah has to stabilize their existence. Really a great short story.

Comment: This is fiction,  but is it SF?  Is it on topic?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Of course it is. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: @user14111, it's a fictional story about either mythological or religious (depending on your view) figures.   Why is that **on** topic?

Comment: @ThePopMachine So you have decided to purge this site of all stories about angels, devils, heaven, and hell? You've got a lot of work ahead of you.

Comment: @user14111, if it's on topic that's fine.   No one will VTC and someone will point to the appropriate meta.

Comment: @ThePopMachine This is on-topic. See, e.g. [this meta answer](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6846/31936). Quoting: "allowances are made for fictional works based on the religions/myths, provided that they are intended as a fictional work, and not a documentary".

Comment: @Null, that makes it not automatically off topic for being about religious figures.   Why is it on topic?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Thanks, Null. Also see DVK's answer [here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3310/14111): "I think the general Meta consensus is that if the writer INTENDS the story to be fiction (e.g., the story of Christ in 'Master and Margarita' by Bulgakov; or Marvel's Asgardians); it's SFF. If it's merely a movie about a religious event ('Passion of Christ' by Mel Gibson; or hell, Charlton Heston's 'Ten Commandments') it's not." I think it's clear that the story described here is more like *The Master and Margarita* than *The Passion of the Christ*.

Comment: @user14111, if I wrote a story about Zeus and Hera discussing what's for dinner,  is it on topic?

Comment: @ThePopMachine This a site for science fiction and fantasy fiction. If it's fantasy fiction then it's on topic. Automatically. The Bible is off-topic, not because it's religious, but because it's non-fiction. Doesn't matter if it's true or false; what matters is, it's *presented* as non-fiction. Likewise *Worlds in Collision* and *Chariots of the Gods* are non-fiction and therefore off-topic.

Comment: If your story about Zeus and Hera gets published, then sure, it's on topic. Before you write it maybe you should read some of the classics like Thorne Smith's *Night Life of the Gods* or Murray Leinster's "The Pipes of Pan".

Comment: @user14111, are you implying that fiction about mythological figures is fantasy?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Fiction about mythological figures (e.g. the comic book *Thor*, Neil Gaiman's *American Gods*) is certainly on topic. Whether such fiction is science fiction or fantasy depends on the approach.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Do you think [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102947/in-star-trek-do-the-greek-gods-lack-nipples) should be closed as off topic?

Comment: @user14111, are we having a conversation or hurling rhetorical remarks?   That question is obviously on topic (and you know it) because first of all, it's Star Trek,  and second of all in the episode Apollo "was part of a group of powerful aliens that visited Earth 50 centuries ago, and thrived on the love, worship, loyalty and attention of the ancient Greek" (wikipedia)

Comment: @ThePopMachine I agree with you: it's not obvious how or why this question is on topic. But we don't seem to get very many of this type of question, so I guess it's not worth worrying about much.

Comment: @anaranjada:   For the record, my upvote on your comment is for the first sentence.   There are others who would take the view that 'we don't seem to get very many' of anything should never be a basis for 'it's not worth worrying about' when it comes to the kinds of things we should allow or question.   (I'm thinking of all kinds of pedantry about tags, for example.)

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure it was a short story? Your description matches the 1984 **novel** [*To Reign in Hell*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?992) by [Steven Brust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Brust). Do any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?992) look familiar? The first sentence of the prologue might ring a bell:

> Snow, tenderly caught by eddying breezes, swirled and spun in to and out of bright, lustrous shapes that gleamed against the emerald-blazoned black drape of sky and sparkled there for a moment, hanging, before settling gently to the soft, green-tufted plain with all the sickly sweetness of an over-written sentence.

Here is a plot summary from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Reign_in_Hell) (emphasis added to highlight points mentioned in the question):

> The story begins by detailing the creation story of Heaven. **There is a substance of raw chaos: cacoastrum; and stuff of order: illiaster. From the illiaster came consciousness that resulted in the firstborn angels: Yaweh, Satan, Michael, Lucifer,** Raphael, Leviathan and Belial. The firstborn create Heaven in order to protect themselves from the cacoastrum, which threatens to destroy them. This event is later referred to as the 'First Wave.' The walls of heaven have collapsed two times since then, resulting in the Second and Third Waves, creating, respectively, the archangels and angels.
>
> After the third wave Heaven has been divided into four regencies named for the cardinal points of the compass. Belial, half-mad and trapped in the form of a dragon, rules the Northern Regency. Leviathan, a kindly woman in the shape of a sea serpent, oversees the Western Regency. Satan rules the South with his loyal servant Beelzebub, trapped in the body of a golden retriever. Lucifer rules the East, with his consort Lilith, who had previously been briefly involved with Satan. Yaweh oversees all of Heaven from the center, aided by his healer Raphael and warrior Michael.
>
> Other important angels include the blind musician Harut, the poetry-quoting Ariel, the craftsman Asmodai, the smirking Mephistopheles, the dour Uriel, the sneering Abdiel, the somewhat naive Gabriel and the coolly competent Zaphkiel. A mostly independent subplot involving two angels named Kyriel and Sith gives the viewpoints of two low-level angels who get swept up in the story's events.
>
> **Trouble arises when Yaweh, worried about the imminent Fourth Wave, devises The Plan: the blueprint for a new, larger Heaven (Earth), with walls that the cacoastrum cannot destroy.** Unfortunately, at least a thousand angels will die during the construction of his new Paradise. Yaweh charges Satan with securing the cooperation of every angel in Heaven, and Satan finds himself wondering if they have the ethical right to coerce anyone into participating.
>
> Exacerbating matters is Abdiel, who craves Satan's rank. Abdiel begins playing Satan against Yaweh, telling each of them that the other will no longer discuss matters. Step by step, the factions escalate. Abdiel attempts to wound Beelzebub and accidentally kills the innocent Ariel. When Satan and Beelzebub attempt to avenge this, Raphael and Michael misinterpret this as proof their opponents have abandoned all decency.
>
> Yaweh, attempting to rally his side, convinces his supporters that he is not only the eldest of the Firstborn, he is God. This announcement stuns not only his opponents, but even Michael, his closest supporter. **Using the energy of his newfound worshipers, he creates a new angel, Yeshuah, who he proclaims his son and heir.**
>
> As the war continues, Zaphkiel intercepts Satan and brings him directly to Yaweh, where the two discover that Abdiel has played them both for fools. However, Satan will not acknowledge Yaweh's dishonest claim to Godhood, and neither will Yaweh abandon it, so the conflict continues.
>
> Abdiel, now on the run from both sides, begins digging a hole in the wall of Heaven, but Mephistopheles finds and strangles him before he can finish the work. Satan's hosts gain the ascendency in the battle. Seeing that defeat is inevitable, Yaweh decides to destroy Heaven by expanding the hole that Abdiel had been deepening. Yet when the wall of Heaven is breached, flooding Heaven with cacoastrum, Yaweh finds that he cannot allow himself to be destroyed by the cacoastrum; it is not in his nature.
>
> Yeshuah, seeing an opportunity to triumph over Satan's forces, sacrifices his life by leaping into the breach and directing the rupture towards the hosts of Satan, devastating them. Meanwhile, as the rebels fight for Heaven, Satan is captured but with the help of Beelzebub and Mephistopheles leaves Heaven; his followers join him in the abyss and create a third stronghold: Hell.