# Who is the shirtless man getting thrown out of a female officer's quarters in Star Trek Beyond (2016), and is it Kirk?

Tags: star-trek, character-identification, star-trek-beyond

At the beginning of the movie, when Kirk is doing his Captain's log voiceover, he speaks about how three years in deep space, cohabiting with the opposite sex, has caused some "effects on interpersonal dynamics." During this voice over we see one young couple kissing, and a red-headed Orion woman throwing a shirtless man out of her quarters, like she's breaking up with him.

I've always thought this shirtless man was Captain Kirk. It looks like him and he slept with a red-headed Orion woman in the first movie (*Star Trek* 2009). But now that I'm rewatching it, we never see this guy's face head-on and the little definition we do see doesn't really look like Kirk. It looks like they put Chekov's head on Kirk's body. I tried looking through the credits but didn't find anyone playing "shirtless man." Also, if it really was Kirk, he wouldn't be listed any differently or more than once.

I really don't care who it is. What I more care about is whether or not it is Kirk. Because I always saw this as a breach of protocol and part of why I don't like Chris Pine's Kirk. Shatner's Kirk would never have sex with a subordinate. He was always talking about how he's married to his ship. But Chris Pine's Kirk is such a horn dog he gets into ethically questionable relationships with his crew. If this is, in fact, NOT Kirk in this scene, then it would totally change how I see his character. Does anyone know who the shirtless man is?

Here's an image, courtesy of @fez:

[image]

Comment: [Here is image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPrp0.jpg) showing the man, but the quality is not the best

Comment: Kirk isn't the only one with an "ethically questionable" relationship (Spock/Uhuru, at a minimum).  But there's plenty of support for even TOS Kirk being a shameless horn dog -- just no evidence (left in the aired film) of him preying on his own crew (Uhuru, Rand, etc.).

Comment: @fez Certainly doesn't look like Chris Pine to me.

Comment: OK, but [does he have nipples?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102947/in-star-trek-do-the-greek-gods-lack-nipples)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## It's (probably*) Chekov.

According to various sources, the "Green Girl" was portrayed by [Fiona Vroom](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2922677/), who shared an image of this scene on Twitter and tagged Chekov's actor Anton Yelchin in it:

> Had a blast filming this scene. @StarTrekMovie #oriongirl #AntonYelchin

([Fiona Vroom on Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/fionavroom/status/760609380811190274))

They are also both tagged in the [same image on IMDB](https://m.imdb.com/name/nm2922677/mediaviewer/rm2159226624), though I am not sure how IMDB content is moderated and curated.

As to how it was possible for Chekov to be thrown out of his quarter and on the bridge at the same time: This whole sequence isn't going on in parallel. There are three things going on, which are not happening at the same time:

- Kirk is getting dressed and starts his shift
- Kirk in voice over does some exposition and recap
- Fitting to the voice over, the Kirk scenes are intercut with everyday scenes from the crew

Chekov being kicked out is part of the latter, to illustrate the voice over:

> The ship aside, prolonged cohabitation has definitely had effects on interpersonal dynamics. Some experiences for the better, and some for the worse (*Chekov gets kicked out)*

*(Star Trek: Beyond)*

*) Another possibility is that it's another officer played by Yelchin, though he was not credited anywhere as such. Prime Video's Xray feature for this scene correctly identifies Fiona Vroom and the Kissing Man and Kissing Woman in the same scene, *and* lists Yelchin as Chekov, but no other mention is made about another character in the scene.

Here is a screenshot of the tweet to counteract Link Rot:
[image: Screenshot of the tweet quoted above]

Answer (score 6):

### I'm pretty sure that officer isn't Kirk...

Firstly, he doesn't look that much like Kirk. He's a little too skinny, his hair is too dark, and his sideburns (or the one we can see, at least) aren't as long as Kirk's.

Secondly, it seems unlikely that a junior officer would physically shove her captain out of a room that way.

Thirdly, just before that, we see a fully-clothed Kirk entering the bridge with a cup of something (I'm guessing coffee) in his right hand. Then we get some other shots, including the one you're referring to. Then we cut back to the bridge, where a fully-clothed Kirk is shown sitting down in the captain's chair, still holding that drink.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So unless those shots are out of chronological order -- and I see no indication that they are -- then Kirk has an alibi, since he was on the bridge when the aforementioned officer was being ejected from the lady's quarters.

As for who the officer *is*, it's presumably just some random officer on the ship who wasn't worth naming in the credits. [IMDB's full cast & crew list for the film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt02660888/fullcredits/) specifies an uncredited [USS Enterprise Crew](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2660888/characters/nm9991092?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t56) member played by [Halit Alptekin](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm9991092/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t56), so that could be the man in question.

Comment: He might be in the credits if he's e.g. also a stunt man. Extras don't get credits (nor usually character names) though, no.

Comment: I would disagree that it's "unlikely that a junior officer would physically shove her captain out of a room that way." It depends what he's done - remember Janice Rand scratched Kirk's face when he tried to assault her. (Of course it was actually the evil side of Kirk's split personality but she didn't know that.)

Comment: @GordonD - I said unlikely, not impossible. Rand scratched the 'evil' Kirk because he was physically forcing himself upon her, and she was terrified of him. Based on what we've seen of him, that sort of behaviour is totally out of character for regular Kirk (either the Pine or Shatner versions), so in practice, he'd almost certainly never elicit such a response, even though it's _theoretically possible_ that he could.